# How to change default wallpapers in custom ISO using cubic?

Tags: 18.04, configuration, custom-distributions, customizer

I have made a custom ISO image using Cubic. I had installed the applications I required and deleted the ones I didn't. 
But I want to change the preset wallpapers, my shell and save my different configuration files so that after installing the ISO everything is just the way I want it.

How do I do this? Where do I place the files and what files do I need to copy?

Comment: is the ISO for ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: @PRATAP Yes, Kubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the command for Ubuntu 18.04 because I use Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm currently running a Lubuntu VM at the moment I posted this, I don't know what that command is, but if you use GNOME you can use `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri` followed by `file:///usr/share/backgrounds/example_wallpaper.jpg` and copy the file you want to use.

Hope this helped.